# how to manage db schema on heroku by play2's evolution?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to manage db schema by evolutions on heroku?
From play2, is the evolution's commandline interface removed?

Answer (score 0):

Play 2 doesn't currently have a CLI for running the evolutions.  You can either auto-run the evolutions or you can manually apply the SQL.